# Preventing denial of service from locking user accounts after too many attempts

Tags: authentication, passwords, denial-of-service

It seems to be common practice to lock user accounts after enough failed attempts in a particular time window.

I am wondering how you prevent denial-of-service attacks since a malicious user who had the username of someone he wished to DoS could simply rapidly make logon attempts.

Is the remedy to lock the account for *only* the IP address of the user who exceeded the logon attempt count+window ?

Is there any better way?

EDIT:

I don't want to make my users solve a captcha on each login attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't block the user by its IP, because maybe it is a real user that forgot his pass and did the retries manually.
The worst thing (business-wise) is that a real user will not be able to access your service.

So, your problem is actually "How do I know that the user is not a robot?".

One of the most popular ways to deal with this is to use a different mechanism for multiple login attempts.
For instance, Google uses Captcha after about 3 trials,
so an automatic bot will get stuck on this stage.

Of course it is possible to get the bot to read the captcha, but it's a start.

You can read more about captcha implementation in their official site: http://www.captcha.net/

Other alternative ideas here: http://econsultancy.com/il/blog/63144-six-alternatives-to-using-the-dreaded-captcha-images